# Difference between "then" and "just then"

Tags: sentence

What is difference between "then" and "just then".

> Thank goodness you were there just then.

I guess "just" is pointing to a short time period between some moment in the past and moment of saying the phrase.

Answer (score 1):

You're right.

**Just then** implies a time-sensitive incident or scenario, some specific moment in which the last minute arrival or sudden appearance of someone either helped prevent something imminent from happening, necessitated some impending event to occur, or otherwise impacted a developing situation, more or less at the last minute.

In other words, if that hadn't happened **just then,** something else *would (or wouldn't) have*.

Such as:

> That guy would have punched my lights out if you hadn't shown up, so
>   **thank goodness you were there just then**.

On the other hand, **then** implies an undefined period of time which could be as short as a minute or two or as long as years or more. However long the span was, it was a time period defined by the presence of another individual who somehow impacted that specific time frame.

Such as:

> I would have lost my job without your help this past November, so
>   **thank goodness you were there then**.

Comment: Thanks fo reply. To clear it. If to say "Thank goodness you were there exactly then." the sense will be the same as "Thank goodness you were there just then."

Comment: Basically yes, but in that particular sentence, it's a bit awkward to say "exactly then." "Just then" sounds more natural and would more likely be spoken by a native English speaker. You'd hear "exactly" more often in a sentence like: "Thank goodness you were there exactly at that moment," or, "...at that exact moment."

Answer (score 0):

He then entered the room. An adverb showing what he did next but it does not really define the moment. It means /next/ and is a logical operator, too.
He entered the room just then. An adverb meaning /at that particular moment/.

As the meaning of then can be confused with next, /just then/ makes the moment unmistakable. Just then means at no other point.